# Ruby on Rails time_select plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, datetime-select

Does anybody know any Ruby on Rails time_select plugins that have only one select box?  So the select box has entries like "9:00 AM", "9:15 AM", etc.?

I have seen a few plugins, but nothing like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want every possible time in 15 minute increments in one select list?  I'd really recommend doing it using the standard time_select plugin.

**Edited to add** I don't know of anything like that, and I don't imagine it'd be out there, you'll probably have to make your own.

Answer (score 9):

I use time_selects ALOT in my apps, and solve time select problems with two minor adjustments.

The first is minute_step:

```
f.time_select :start_of_shift, :minute_step => 15
```

This will cut that heinous minute select box into a very managable size (choose your own!)

Also, I found a ruby module that I place i my initializer folder of all my time based apps:

```
module ActionView
module Helpers
class DateTimeSelector
def select_hour_with_twelve_hour_time 
  datetime = @datetime
  options = @options
  return select_hour_without_twelve_hour_time(datetime, options) unless options[:twelve_hour].eql? true
  if options[:use_hidden]
    build_hidden(:hour, hour)
  else
    val = datetime ? (datetime.kind_of?(Fixnum) ? datetime : datetime.hour) : ''
    hour_options = []
    0.upto(23) do |hr|
      ampm = hr <= 11 ? ' AM' : ' PM'
      ampm_hour = hr == 12 ? 12 : (hr / 12 == 1 ? hr % 12 : hr)              
      hour_options << ((val == hr) ?               
      %(<option value="#{hr}" selected="selected">#{ampm_hour}#{ampm}</option>\n) :               
      %(<option value="#{hr}">#{ampm_hour}#{ampm}</option>\n)             
      )
    end           

    build_select(:hour, hour_options)         
  end       
  end       
  alias_method_chain :select_hour, :twelve_hour_time     
  end   
end
end
```

I wish I could remember where I found it so I could credit the source, but in a nutshell, it allows me to specify 12-hour time breaking down my time_select fields to two easy selects that are very easy to manage.

```
f.time_select :start_of_shift, :twelve_hour => true, :minute_step => 15
```

EDIT: Found the source of the ruby file! Find it here: http://brunomiranda.com/past/2007/6/2/displaying_12_hour_style_time_select/

Comment: yes i have seen that as well, but it doesn't do the job in one select.  i should be finished coding the solution in an hour or so.  i'll post it soon

Comment: I modified the above answer to work with Rails 3, and to have 12 am instead of 0 am.  See: https://gist.github.com/1340125.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a really basic helper, put this in your application helper.  You would have to convert the time in your controller/model with Time.parse(params[:your_field]).  This probably doesn't solve your problem, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

```
def time_select_tag(name)
  times = []
  (00..23).each do |i|
    (0..3).each { |inc| times << Time.parse("#{i}:#{inc * 15}") }
  end
  return select_tag name, options_for_select(times.map{|t| t.strftime('%I:%M%p')})
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [12_hour_time](http://code.google.com/p/rails-twelve-hour-time-plugin/)?  This has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Rails [ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select) class has a solution for this

```
<%= f.time_select :attribute_name, :minute_step => 15, :ampm => true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this with Rails 3, you'll need to assign `html_options` to an empty string (`html_options = ""`). `build_select` requires the select options to be html. Otherwise you will receive `can't convert Array into String`.

See the [build_select](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L985.) documentation.

Just a friendly update. Enjoy.